# When huge logs data is flushed, Getting below buffer overflow throw_exception and BufferOverflowError in fluent (td-agent version:1.6)

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

```
[warn]: #0 failed to write data into buffer by buffer overflow action=:throw_exception

[warn]: #0 emit transaction failed: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::Buffer::BufferOverflowError error="buffer space has too many data" location="/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fluentd-1.6.3/lib/fluent/plugin/buffer.rb:298:in `write'" tag="bro.logs.conn"
  2023-06-28 14:40:30 +0530 [warn]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
```

I have gone through the fluent td official documentation
https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section#flushing-parameters.

I guess, something from these flushing parameters should work,
but i don't know where exactly to configure.

Please add any other solutions or suggestion.

Comment: Please include your configuration file in your question. It's hard to say anything about it without looking at your config. Thanks!